# Misplaced Matters - When Words Lost Their Way!

Tags: rhyme, steganography

> **D**eciphering hidden code, will take some time
>   Lost is your **e**quipment here, help will be mine.
>
> Inspecting this poem, sh<s>a</s>**a**ll give some hope
>   Don't da**r**e demand me **t**o **h**elp, w**i**ll alway**s** just mope.
>
> Seem**s** like your mind just went **t**o freeze
>   **U**nknown locked up in here rest some word.
>
> I**f** this poem seem aloo**f**, please jo**i**n my ride.
>   This poem promise**s** to expose whatever it choose to length.
>
> Some of us, tend to take my poem to be kind of mean
>   A**n**d some just find hidden treasure uneven.
>
> Cam**o**uflaged sits **t**hat code in here my friend
>   Purely hiding things is what need to be kenned.
>
> Things that stay ba**c**kwards, proves w**o**rthy always
>   Beginnings doesn't always, gets what it pays.
>
> If some pe**r**son checks ugly scheme atop in heaven,
>   They will give up then, things will just look within.
>
> Show me f**r**iend, show m**e** your strength,
>   Surprise me with your brainy keys.
>
> My poem offers jewels as well as sw<s>o</s>ord
>   It will lend to my solver ni**c**e lit**t**le hide.

And, here's the reward for solving the puzzle -

> Cqpjjl crwf ejqsvg izkefbtj.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First we saw that

> The bold letters form the sentence: "Dear this stUff's not correct"

Because of this, we noticed...

> that some of the rhymes are misplaced

To correct them, we need to

> Change the place of some of the final words.
>
>  *OP Edit:* As the title says, the *misplaced things matters* and *the words have lost their way*, so, we just need to place them right.

So we get:

> Deciphering hidden code, will take some time
>  Lost is your equipment here, help will be mine.
>
>  Inspecting this poem, shall give some hope
>  Don't dare demand me to help, will always just mope.
>
>  Seems like your mind just went to freeze
>  Unknown locked up in here rest some keys.
>
>  If this poem seem aloof, please join my ride.
>  This poem promises to expose whatever it choose to hide.
>
>  Some of us, tend to take my poem to be kind of mean
>  And some just find hidden treasure within.
>
>  Camouflaged sits that code in here my friend
>  Purely hiding things is what need to be kenned.
>
>  Things that stay backwards, proves worthy always
>  Beginnings doesn't always, gets what it pays.
>
>  If some person checks ugly scheme atop in heaven,
>  They will give up then, things will just look uneven.
>
>  Show me friend, show me your strength,
>  Surprise me with your brainy length.
>
>  My poems offers jewel as well as sword
>  It will lend to my solver nice little word.

And

> The words we needed to change place were: "keys", "hide", "within", "uneven", "length", "word".

Which reveals that

> There is some information in words with odd ("uneven") length.

So taking all of those words we get:

> **D**eciphering **e**quipment Seem**s** **U**nknown aloo**f** a**n**d Cam**o**uflaged ba**c**kwards

And

> All of these words have bold letters forming the word "DesUfnoc" which is the word "confused" backwards (thanks @Jan Ivan and @M Oehm).

Using this as a

> key in a Vigenere cipher, the reward for solving the puzzle would be: "accept your reward glxzljpg."

And with this we have a

> Grand reward, indeed ! [image] (thanks @Hose Pipe). Check the picture's URL to understand...